# General structure of solutions to 3-SAT circuits

Tags: satisfiability, 3-sat, constraint-satisfaction, 2-sat

Certain special forms of the SAT problem have solution sets of a special form. For example, given any three solutions to a 2-SAT circuit, their bitwise median is also a solution. Likewise, given any three solutions to an XOR-SAT circuit, their bitwise XOR is also a solution. Lastly, given any two solutions to a HORN-SAT circuit, their bitwise AND is also a solution.

Does there exist a similar situation for 3-SAT, where given some subset of solutions, one can somehow generate additional solutions?

If not, does there exist a related SAT problem that 3-SAT can be reduced to, and hence which is also NP-complete, which have solutions of the form specified? For instance 1-in-3 SAT, or exactly-3-SAT, or NAE-3-SAT, or etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theory you are after is *universal algebra*. See the excellent expository article of Hubie Chen, [A rendezvous of logic, complexity, and algebra](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0611018.pdf), which contains a streamlined proof of [Schaefer’s dichotomy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem), which was recently extended to arbitrary alphabets.

3SAT has no polymorphisms. NAE-3SAT has only negation as a polymorphism. All other classes of polymorphisms correspond to CSPs solvable in polynomial time. See [Allender et al., The Complexity of Satisfiability Problems: Refining Schaefer’s Theorem](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/pub/cspJCSS.pdf).